# How do I make a transparent object glow from within in Blender 3.0?

Tags: materials

[image]I have looked this up and there are tutorials for older versions and they have shader nodes that aren't in Blender 3.0.  I have tried just experimenting but I am not getting anything near the results I want

I am trying to make individual transparent spheres glow from within.  I can make to object glow with the emission but that is not the effect I am look for.  I want prismatic light to glow from within the the spheres. OR have a glow from with shine through a prismatic sphere.. like a transparent
pearlescent sphere.

*** Ok this is screenshot of what came up with after tinkering with the answer below and attempting to add the prismatic effect. I really want the colors to be brighter and the light to look as if it is shining through multicolored crystal.  I experimented with different refraction values and the higher values wash out the colors more.  Any tips to achieving this would be appreciated.

I'd appreciate any help I can get to make this happen with Blender 3.0.  Thanx in advance

Comment: please add an image to you question how it should look like. Even 1000 words cannot describe it better than an image. Because otherwise people who answer waste their time on writing an answer because you want something completely different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you're going for, but maybe try something like this (first image is in Cycles):

[image: GlassGlow]

Here is the same setup in EEVEE, with some minor tweaks to the *Layer Weight* values. Try experimenting with changing them yourself, and see if you can get close to what you're looking for.

[image: GlassGlow2]

If you want a "Spectral Hue", create a ColorRamp with a spectrum, and connect it with a Gradient texture (I chose diagonal because it seems "prism-y"), and connect it as the color of the emission. If you want a "deeper" color to the glass, connect it to the Refraction color input as well. The Vector math is optional - you can do just fine with just "generated" coordinates, but the Vector Math gives more options - both in combinations of vectors to combine, but also in the different "math operations" that can be used to combine them - some give pretty funky results ;)

[image: Spectral]

Comment: I got it to work as in your description.  Still experimenting with getting the prismatic glow.  Thank you so much.

Comment: II could probably help more if I knew exactly what you mean by "prismatic" - do you mean color-wise - like, show the spectrum?

Comment: Prismatic is splitting into rainbow colors like a prism.

Comment: I tried to hook things up exactly as in the last diagram and I cannot find that ADD node anywhere.  Nothing that looks like that node at all.  The math node say add but the inputs are are not vectors.  I am using Blender 3.0.  I know thatthey changed the shader nodes.  That is why I haven't has any luck replicating other tutorials.

Comment: The node is called _Vector Math_ (under _Converter_ - second from bottom). The default operation for it is _Add_.